# JNI how to manage the life cycle of a c++ buffer

Tags: android, c++11, java-native-interface, shared-ptr, shared-memory

I have an image buffer allocated on the heap in my c++ code that I would like to share with some other c++ objects as well as Java objects through JNI. On the native side im using shared_ptr and I was wondering what is the best way to do so ? my thought is to allocate the buffer on the heap once and share a reference everywhere. I'm taking advantage of smart pointers so that the buffer will be deallocated as soon as all the references go out of scope, but I'm facing an issue when sharing a reference to the java side.

how can I ensure that my java object has a valid reference to the buffer all the time ? how can c++ determine that the reference counter reaches 0 when java object is done using its reference. My concern is to avoid memory leak and also ensure that buffer doesn't get destroyed too soon before getting processed by the java class.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is "make the Java object's lifetime influence the lifetime of the C++ object".

Start with the following Java class:

```java
class Refholder implements AutoCloseable {
    private long ptr; // the actual pointer
    private long shared_ptr; // a pointer to a shared_ptr keeping `ptr` alive
    public Refholder(long ptr, long shared_ptr) {
        this.ptr = ptr;
        this.shared_ptr = shared_ptr;
    }
    public native void close();
    public void finalize() { close(); }
    // Other methods to access the contents of `ptr` go here.
};
```

This will contain both the actual pointer and a pointer to a `shared_ptr`.

When you want to hand a reference to Java, use the following:

```cpp
jobject passToJava(JNIEnv *env, std::shared_ptr<Foo> instance) {
    jclass cls_Refholder = env->FindClass("Refholder");
    jmethodID ctr_Refholder = env->GetMethodID(cls_Refholder, "<init>", "(JJ)V");
    // This line increases the reference count and remembers where we put the copy
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> *copy = new std::shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(instance));
    jobject ret = env->NewObject(cls_Refholder, ctr_Refholder, copy->get(), copy);
    return ret;
}
```

Finally, the `close` method is responsible for extracting the `shared_ptr` and deallocating it:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void Java_Refholder_close(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass cls_Refholder = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jfieldID fld_Refholder_ptr = env->GetFieldID(cls_Refholder, "ptr", "J");
    jfieldID fld_Refholder_shared_ptr = env->GetFieldID(cls_Refholder, "shared_ptr", "J");

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> *copy = (std::shared_ptr<Foo>*)env->GetLongField(obj, fld_Refholder_shared_ptr);
    if (!copy)
        return;

    env->SetLongField(obj, fld_Refholder_ptr, 0);
    env->SetLongField(obj, fld_Refholder_shared_ptr, 0);
    delete copy;
}
```

I have decided to implement both `AutoCloseable` and `finalize` because I do not know how your Java code plans to use the reference. If you need deterministic destruction of the C++ object you need to use `try-with-resources` or explicit calls to the `close` method. If you do not, at last the `finalize` will close it.

Comment: thank you for the help. I understand the passToJava part and it makes perfect sense, but as to the close() native function, I don't want to call delete on the buffer and destroy it if other c++/java objects are still using it. I just want the reference counter to go down and when it reaches 0 it would automatically deallocate the buffer.

Comment: That is exactly what the `delete copy` does: it destroys one instance of `std::shared_ptr`, which will decrease the refcount in the control block by 1. It is the same mechanism as when a `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope. Only if the refcount reaches 0 (ie this was the last reference) is it destroyed.

Comment: It is up to you to prevent one Java thread from calling `close()` while another is still using the object. You could for example simulate copy construction by implementing and using a `native Object clone()` method.